# PHP using wildcard for accessing JSON object

Tags: php, json, wildcard

I'm trying to access to a specific key. Here is my object :

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [ext-118-27-16-0-23] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [version] => 6 
            [addr] => 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:C0A8:0001
        ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [version] => 4 
            [addr] => 192.168.0.1 
        ) 
    )
)
```

In this case I'm expecting to ouput the value `192.168.0.1` of the key `addr`. The first key (`ext-118-27-16-0-23`) change and I don't know his value.
The pattern should looks like `ext-*`

So I guess I need something like that :

```
$addr = {WILDCARD}[1]->addr;
```

Comment: If you're getting that from JSON, use `json_decode($input, true);` to get an associative array. Then you can use `array_values` appropriately.

Comment: I tried but how to use the function ? It's not really precise if the order change

Comment: Is there only ever one top-level property in your object? Ie, only one `ext-118-27-16-0-23`

Comment: Yes there is only one key named like that

Comment: I don't just mean the name. Are there any other properties at that level?

Comment: @Phil, No there is no other properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I think you can do

```php
$ipv4Addresses = array_map(function($ip) {
    return $ip->addr;
}, array_filter(current((array) $obj), function($ip) {
    return $ip->version === 4;
}));
```

This will return an array of all the IPv4 `addr` properties.

Notable points:

- Cast the object to an array ~ `(array) $obj`
- Use `current()` to extract the first (only) property
- Use `array_filter()` to reduce the array of addresses to `version` 4
- Use `array_map()` to extract only the `addr` property

You may want to use `array_values()` on the final array to re-index it from `0`.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/LfDg8